# I want to use two method of models in foreach loop

Tags: foreach, codeigniter-3

Hi I want to use two methods of model in single foreach loop. but it get's me error........
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

I got error in view where I am using
PLO_weightage; ?>" min="1">

I have updated my question and add also methods of model
My Controller

```
public function assign_PLO($subj_session){
    $data2 = array();

$data['data']=$this->portal->assign_subject_teacher_PLO($subj_session);

    $data2['data2']=$this->PLO->PLO_detail();
    $data2['data3'] = $this->portal->max_weightage_assign($subj_session);

            $this->load->view('Teacher/Header');
        $this->load->view('Teacher/PLO_subj_assign',$data+$data2);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
```

My view

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                PLO Assign
                <hr>
                <div class="row" >
                <?php
                if($data3){ 
         if($data2){

    foreach($data2 as $tab){

    ?>
    <div class=" col-md-4  text-left"> 



    <div class="form-group alert alert-dark">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" value="<?php echo $tab->PLO_id;?>" name="assign_PLO[]" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck" >   
<?php echo $tab->PLO_name;?> </label>

        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="assign_wt[]" max="<?php echo $data3->PLO_weightage; ?>" min="1">  

         </div>
  </div>

</div>

<?php 
         } 
        }
}
       ?>
```

Model

```
public function PLO_detail(){

    $query = $this->db->get('plo');


    if($query->num_rows() >0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}




public function max_weightage_assign($subj_session){

    $this->db->select_sum('PLO_weightage');
    $this->db->select('PLO_weightage');
    $this->db->where('session',$subj_session);
    $this->db->group_by('PLO_id');

    $query=$this->db->get('plo_data');

    if($query->num_rows() >0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hmm ok so first question...why are you even using $data2 as an array when you are already using $data? $data['data'], $data['data2'] and $data['data3'] ( bad variable naming but I guess this is just quick knock up code for testing and not for real use ).

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes I am testing my Code... Please give seggestion. how can I remove error and get answer...

Comment: Well what I should have asked was - If your question is involving a model, could you please add the code for it to your question so we can see it?

Comment: Please check it. I have added methods of model. Thank you

Comment: Ok so what do you get when you perform a print_r($data) and print_r($data2) after you have assigned them, so in your controller?

Comment: it's long array and i can't ri8 it in single comment

Comment: Array ( [data2] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 0 [PLO_name] => Engineering knowledge [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 1 [PLO_name] => Problem Analysis [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 2 [PLO_name] => Design/Development of Solutions [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 3 [PLO_name] => Investigation [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 4 [PLO_name] => Modern Tool Usage [PLO_t_pr] => 100 )

Comment: [5] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 5 [PLO_name] => The Engineer and Society [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 6 [PLO_name] => Environment and Sustainability [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 7 [PLO_name] => Ethics [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 8 [PLO_name] => Individual and Teamwork [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 9 [PLO_name] => Communication [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 10 [PLO_name] => Project Managment [PLO_t_pr] => 100 )

Comment: [11] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_id] => 11 [PLO_name] => Lifelong Learning [PLO_t_pr] => 100 ) ) [data3] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_weightage] => 10 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_weightage] => 5 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_weightage] => 15 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [PLO_weightage] => 15 ) ) )

Comment: This is full that i got

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and add that into it so its formatted...